# Why is stdin/stdout failing with gplay on ubuntu?

Tags: sound, java, stdout

I am trying to change gplay's volume level programmatically in a Java app. The video plays fine; I see gplay's menu; I get my first "Playing" prompt, and I write a "v" for "[v]Volume" but I never see the volume prompt "Set volume." I get all of the data I expect from BufferedReader, but BufferedWriter does not seem to be working. Everything works as expected when I run gplay from the console. Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Thank you.

```
List<String> command = new ArrayList<String>();
command.add("gplay");
command.add("demoVideo.mp4");

ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(command);
builder.directory(new File("/home/ubuntu"));
builder.redirectErrorStream(true);

Process playVideoProcess = builder.start();

// get the input stream connected to the normal output of the subprocess
InputStream is = playVideoProcess.getInputStream();
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);

// get the output stream connected to the normal input of the subprocess
OutputStream os = playVideoProcess.getOutputStream();
OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(os);
BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(osw);

while (true)
{
    line = br.readLine();
    if (line != null)
    {
        if (debug) logger.log(Level.INFO, "--> " + line);

        if (line.contains("[Playing  ][Vol=01]"))
        {
            bw.write("v");
            bw.newLine();
            bw.flush();
        }
        else if (line.contains("Set volume"))
        {
            bw.write("10");
            bw.newLine();
            bw.flush();
        }
        else if (line.contains("[Playing  ][Vol=10]"))
        {
            logger.log(Level.INFO, "* Done. CLOSING ALL STREAMS *");
            bw.close();
            osw.close();
            os.close();

            br.close();
            isr.close();
            is.close();
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `gplay` ? is it an app from Ubuntu repositories ?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, Serg - it's a streaming  media player from Freescale Semiconductor. Here's a link to the PDF manual:

https://www.element14.com/community/servlet/JiveServlet/downloadBody/49378-102-1-259394/Freescale.Application_Note_1.pdf